# Switching between Flex mobile applications using Air Native Extentions for Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I'm building two different Flex Mobile applications for Android. Those two applications should  be able to call each other by presseing a button (one each app), meaning that those buttons would allow a sort of switch between these applications.

My questions are:
- Is it possible to call another Flex Mobile application with Air Native Extentions?
- Could one Air Native Extension's instance be shared between two applications?
- How can this be done? Any possible examples would be deeply appreciated.

Regards,

Sebastián